# Debugger in remix ethereum.org shows function return value as 'Object'

Tags: debugging, solidity, remix

I have recently started learning solidity and experimenting with Remix IDE in remix.ethereum.org. I have noticed that the function return values in debug mode are always denoted as '0:Object' instead of for example '0:uint' [example of return value in debugger mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLuAJ.png). Is this a designing feature or an error?